# DB2 issue with CASE and adding days to date

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to get a selection of records where the date field of the record(s) is current date + 7 Days

I was previously doing this in MySQL like so:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ( d.next_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dateCount
```

But now trying to do this on DB2 it's not working

```
SUM(case WHEN f.next_date + 7 days then 1 else 0 end) as dateCount
```

I'm wondering why this would be, but I'm simply trying to get a count of all records where the date is today + 7 days.

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your case expression is **lacking a comparison**, e.g. `when (some_value is compared to other_value) then do_something ...`. Perhaps an equal?

```
SUM(case when {date field of the record} = f.next_date + 7 days then 1 else 0 end) as dateCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sum(case when f.next_date = current date + 7 day then 1 end) as dateCount
from table(values
  current date + 1 day
, current date + 7 day
, current date + 7 day
) f(next_date);
```